# Help Optimizing a Support for an All-Ranged Party

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization

We are currently going to a campaign with no real frontliners, we have an archer ranger, a blaster sorc, an artillerist artificer and a gunslinger(Mat Mercer). I thought of trying to be a support but as I was going through some spells, I found that most of the "support spells" like battlefield-control and debuffs are more useful in Melee parties(like Hold Person not giving the free crit to ranged attacks and the like).

Playing a Tanky character doesn't seem like a good alternative cause I would screw up with the entire party trying to stealth. If not, I would be the only one in the Frontline and I dont think I have the required game Sense to survive by myself.

Can I be an effective support or should I try something else entirely? Like, How could I not build a waste of a character and contribute to my party?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. As written, your question seems a bit too opinion-based to be answerable (we can't really tell you what you "should" do), as well as being quite broad. If you narrow down what exactly you're looking for, we might be able to better answer it.

Comment: "Needs more focus" close-voters and those inclined that way: I'd urge you to give [type II charop](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1641/23970) another read and consider leaving a comment telling KimMaximus what changes you think would make the question answerable.

Comment: The main problem imo is that that "support" is an extremely generic term that can mean anything from healer, buffer, controller, etc. The question either needs to narrow down to a more specific role to ask "how to optimize that role given this party" OR it needs to backup and ask "which role does this party need most". In either case some additional requirements to narrow the possible answers would be nice, more stuff along the lines of "not abysmal at stealth".

Answer (score 1):

### Consider a stealthy dex-based "tank" build

You say that you don't want to play a tank because you would drag down the overall stealthiness of the party, presumably because "tanky" implies low dexterity and maybe some loud clanky armor. However, there are other ways to fill the "tank" role. The option I'd recommend is a monk with the sentinel feat. Monks get Unarmored Defense, which lets them add their wisdom modifier to their AC, and you can be tanky by saving most of your ki points to use on Patient Defense to give enemy attacks disadvantage against you. Instead of soaking up lots of damage, you soak up lots of attacks by making sure they miss much more often. (And of course you also have Deflect Missiles for incoming ranged attacks, but be careful about using it since it uses your reaction.) Meanwhile, the sentinel feat allows you to hold the line by stopping an enemies in their tracks with your opportunity attacks. In addition, the most common condition you inflict is stunned (via Stunning Strike), which is equally beneficial for ranged attacks and melee attacks (both gain advantage against the target). Out of combat, you're going to have a high dexterity modifier, excellent mobility, and you can choose Stealth as one of your skill proficiencies, so you should be more than capable of keeping up on a stealth mission.

You can see an example of a build similar to this in the character of Beauregard from Critical Role Campaign 2. Beau isn't the perfect example, since the group isn't strongly stealth-focused, and Beau doesn't always prioritize Patient Defense in battle, but she does demonstrate the power of the hard-to-hit monk sentinel build as a capable front-line fighter.

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part about this situation is that you are optimizing one PC to *support* 4 other PCs.

5e's fundamental design is that no class is really designed to benefit from, or for another, especially in combat. Each class has their own fundamental strengths an weaknesses. In this case, the issue of having an all-ranged party means that there is very little stopping the enemy from charging, and getting in close, therefore exploiting their weakness.

So I feel there you have 3 options: be the front-guard, and draw attention to yourself, so that the enemy is more concerned with you, than the rest of the party; the "defensive" spell caster, that uses spells and abilities to stop the enemy from advancing; or the "buffer" use spells and abilities to help benefit your party when the enemy do eventually charge.

### Front-Guard

This role is going to have to be all tank. Even to the point where you aren't necessarily dealing much damage, you're just able to withstand everything the enemy throws at you, and draw their attention away from the rest of the party. In this situation, you've got a few things to consider.

**Stats:** ultimately, your primary stat is going to be CON, for them hit points. You want as much health as you can carry. This could be swapped for your DEX*, or at least on par with it, to reduce damage that you receive. Not getting hit is just as good at taking less damage, but there's always a chance you'll be hit, so you don't want to go down the first time you do get hit.

**Race:** Here's where you got a few options. only a few races give a boost to CON, and all have their own special features to help out in one way or another.

- Dwarf: CON bonus of +2, gain resistance to poison damage, and adv to save vs. poison. Hill Dwarfs gain *Dwarven Toughness* (extra hp), and Mountain Dwarfs gain Proficiency with light and Medium Armour.
- Human: They gain +1 to every stat, but I would ask your GM if you can use the Variant Human in this situation, for the +2 to one stat, or +1 to two stats (again, focus on CON), with the added bonus of a free feat. Some suggestions might be:

  - *Durable*: Increase CON by 1 (max 20) and regain extra hp when you roll a hit die
  - *Sentinel*: Hitting an enemy with an opportunity attack reduces their speed to 0; you can still attack enemies within 5ft with opportunity attacks, even if they disengage; and if a target within 5ft of you attacks someone else, you get an opportunity attack on that target.
- Half-Orc: +2 STR, +1 CON; *Relentless Endurance* and *Savage Attacker* are a huge bonus here.

**Class:** There are a couple of ways you can go here, depending on how you want to play.

- Barbarian: This is the build that you're going to use in order to get among the enemy, with the intention of having all of them focused on you. You're big, you're loud, and you wanna smash. At level 3 you can choose a Primal path, which gives you a few options, but I'd suggest the Bear Totem warrior, to make you more resilient.
- Fighter: Probably not the best choice here, but it does open up *a lot* of avenues. You can go with the Battle Master, for the manouvres which you could use to either move your teammates to more beneficial positions, or out of combat for free; or go with Eldritch Knight, to make you more versatile, both in and out of combat. Fighter do also have the ability to fight at range as well, so you could use this as an option to keep back with the rest of the party.
- Paladin: This is probably your best bet for this build. Not only do you get access to armour, shields, and decent weaponry, you also gain access to defensive fighting styles and spellcasting, including healing as a base class ability. So when the fighting's done, you can go around and help patch up those in need of a few hit points.

### Defensive Caster

The primary purpose of this build is based on a specific set of spells, and potentially abilities to use in order to stop the enemy from getting into combat with your party.

**Stats and Race:** This build is all about the spells you use. In which case, your stats, and potentially your race are going to be based on which class you go with.

**Class:** This one is pretty limited. The idea is to have spells in your repertoire that are going to stall and hinder the enemy as much as possible.

- Druid: The druid has access to a couple of good spells that can help keep the enemy at a distance. The trade-off is that you only have access to a limited number of spell slots, as your primary ability is Wild Shape. Wild Shape on it's own is incredibly versatile, allowing you to gain extra hit points (you gain the hit points of the animal when you transform), new abilities, and multiple transformations, as your skill develops. However, some of the spells you have access to can be handy in holding off the enemy:

  - *Fog Wall* cuts off line of sight (makes the area heavily obscured, but doesn't stop the enemy from advancing. this could be useful when you and the party need to create some ground between you and the enemy
  - *Entangle* is great for slowing down the enemy, but unfortunately doesn't cut off line of sight.
  - *Thunderwave* pushes enemies back 10 ft if they fail a STR saving throw, with the added bonus of dealing damage.
- Wizard: This is the opther option I'd suggest, as they have a *massive* array of spells to access, as well as a decent number of spell slots. The downside is that you only have access to a certain number of them at a time, equal to your INT modifier + Wizard level, to spread across all your spell levels. The other downside is that you're not so hot in close combat yourself.

### Buff Caster

This one can be the most versatile, and potentially the most fun (IMO). Not just for you, but for the whole party. The idea here is that you are going to be aiding the rest of the party by boosting their own abilities, in any way you see might be necessary.

**Stats and Race:** again, like the "Defense" option, this is going to be dependent on which class you choose.

**Class:** Again, there are a couple of options here, depending on which way you want to go.

- Bard: The bard is a proper support class, and a flamboyant one at that. Not only are they able to aid the rest of the party by boosting their abilities with Bardic Inspiration* and even abilities like *Combat Inspiration* once you reach higher levels, they also have access to spells that can switch things up, as well as having fun throwing insults that *literally* wound.

  - *Faerie Fire* can grant advantage on enemies (if they fail a DEX saving throw)
  - *Heroism* grants temporary Hit Points
- Sorcerer: Because these guys create chaos. The trick is to embrace the Wild Surge table. Let's be real here; anything can happen. Even when you turn the gun slinger into a Unicorn for three rounds. In addition, you also have the ability to regain spell slots, or boost the damage and efficacy of your spells on the fly, depending on what you need.

---

In all honesty, you should pick the way that you want to play, because if it becomes a task to play a certain kind of character, you're not going to have fun. So remember you want to make it *fun* for yourself, more than you want to make it *easier* for everyone else.